# How to get unique element names from XMLs stored in MarkLogic DB, when DB size is too big?

Tags: marklogic

I am using ML 9

In MarkLogic database, there are 2.8 million xml documents.
I just want to get all the unique element names.

As the database size is too large, what is the best & fastest way to get the unique element names?

Comment: Do all the documents have the same root element name? Are they broken up into any sort of collections or URI conventions that would allow you to query element names in smaller chunks?

Comment: No root element is not same, all the documents are in default collection. There is no URI convention!

Answer (score 2):

You could run a [CORB job](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) that selects all of the URIs from the database in your URIs module, and then returns a distinct list of element names using either `name()` or `local-name()` in the process module, with the `PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask` option to write all of the output to a single file, and the `POST-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PostBatchUpdateFileTask` and `EXPORT-FILE-SORT=ascending|distinct` options to dedup, and generate a distinct list of element names from the database in a text file.

An example job with all of the necessary options, except for the [`XCC-CONNECTION-URI`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#XCC-CONNECTION-URI):

```
# Inline module to select all URIs
URIS-MODULE=INLINE-XQUERY|xdmp:estimate(fn:doc()), cts:uris("",(),cts:true-query())

# Inline module to return a distinct list of element names in the document on a separate line
PROCESS-MODULE=INLINE-XQUERY|declare variable $URI as xs:string external; string-join(fn:distinct-values(fn:doc($URI)//*/name()),"&#10;")

# Write the results of each process module to a single file
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=element-names.txt

# After the batch processing is completed, sort and dedup the element names
POST-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PostBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-SORT=ascending|distinct

THREAD-COUNT=10
```